# Replace Dojo NumberTextBox separator comma with a hyphen

Tags: javascript, dojo

How do I replace the comma formatting in a Dojo NumberTextBox with hyphen? 
For example: Convert 123,456,789 into 123-456-789.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really a number anymore as much as a string pattern you want to preserve that happens to have numbers in it (I suppose you could say you want the thousands separator to be a dash instead of a comma?  dojo.number.format supports overriding the thousands separator, but I don't think NumberTextBox does)

I owe you an example, but doughays says the way to do this would be to create a subclass of ValidationTextBox which provides a regexp matching the pattern you desire for the display/input and overrides parse and format methods to transform the number to/from that pattern.

Comment: Hi Peller, Thanks for the reply. You are right, I want a hyphen in place of comma. On the backend I dont need to preserve this as the value is stored without any hyphens or commas. Any good example to subclass ValidationTextBox and implement this?

Comment: solved it. Used ValidationTextBox and got rid of comma's permanently :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar for phone number inputs. This reformats a **ValidationTextBox** value as ###-###-####. (I elected not to use dojo/number because I already had an Array of digits and adding the dashes with splice is fairly straightforward)

The default **filter** method comes from **_TextBoxMixin.js**, which is where trim, uppercase, lowercase, and propercase is implemented.

```
declare('calpoly/form/FormattingPhoneNumber', [ValidationTextBox], {

    regExp:"\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}",
    invalidMessage:"Please enter a 10-digit phone number",

    filter:function(val){
        val = lang.trim(val);
        var s = [];
        for(var i=0; i<val.length;i++){
            if(!isNaN(val[i])){
                s.push(val[i]);
            }
        }
        if(s.length!=10){
            // Not a 10-digit phone number, return what the user typed, regex will invalidate.
            return val;
        }
        s.splice(3,0,'-');
        s.splice(7,0,'-');
        return s.join('');
    }
});
```